# How to get Comma Separated Cell Value in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for validation.

If previous cell has two comma separated values then this cell is mandatory otherwise it is not mandatory.

Example:
A and B are cells.
Foo, Bar, Ice are the cell values.
If A cell contain "Foo,Bar" (without quotes) then B cell is mandatory.

Some code I am using throwing alert message.

```
list = Split(Sheet1.UsedRange.Cells(rowIndex, 18), ",")
count = 0
For Each part In list 
  Dim temp 
  temp = Trim(Encode(part)) 
  If temp <> "" Then 
    count = count + 1
  End If
Next
```

Comment: showing your code that you have so far or the pertinent parts may be of use.

Comment: Hi ForwardEd, I have done that using.list = Split(Sheet1.UsedRange.Cells(rowIndex, 18), ",")
            count = 0
            For Each part In list
                Dim temp
                temp = Trim(Encode(part))
                If temp <> "" Then
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was long time ago I posted but I did not answer to the post, This is how I have achieved the functionality.

```
list = Split(Sheet1.UsedRange.Cells(rowIndex, 18), ",") 
count = 0
For Each part In list 
Dim temp
temp = Trim(Encode(part)) If temp <> "" Then count = count + 1 
End If 
Next
```